# Paste value based on index match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to get a macro(button click) to paste a value into another sheet if the value is not a formula. I'm not getting any errors with the below but the function won't fire. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
Sub Update_Numbers(ByVal Target As Range)

' Update_Numbers Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+j

On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)

Case Sheets("Wage Run").Range("B7")
    If Target.HasFormula = False Then _
        Sheets("wage run").Range("B7").Copy
        Sheets("With Changes").Select
        Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("With Changes").Range("E2:AB138"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Wage Run").Range("D1"), Sheets("With Changes").Range("A2:A138"), 0), 1)).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Select

Safe_Exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

EDIT: Changed with the below suggestions, but it still won't fire.

```
Sub Update_Numbers(ByVal Target As Range)
With Sheets("wage run")
' Update_Numbers Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+j

On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
Application.EnableEvents = False

Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)


Case "B7"
If Target.HasFormula = False Then
    Sheets("wage run").Range("B7").Copy
    Sheets("With Changes").Select
    Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("With Changes").Range("E2:AB138"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Wage Run").Range("D1"), Sheets("With Changes").Range("A2:A138"), 0), 1)).Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,     SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End If
End Select

Safe_Exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Take your error check out and you will see why,  Target is nothing.

Comment: Unless you are providing the range to the sub via another sub calling this one it will not do anything because Target does not get automatically set unless it is one of the worksheet events that allows for it, just putting the words in the parenthesis does not make it happen.  It is causing an error at `Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)` because Target is nothing and nothing has no address.  Take out the lines `On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
Application.EnableEvents = False`. right now you are skipping everything because of the error control is sending it to the end.

Comment: I'm confused by this as I have a similar code in another worksheet.     `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("$B$1:$C$1")) Is Nothing Then
            Range("B8").Formula = salaries2
        End If
    
    Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
        Case "B1"
            Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            
        Case "B8"
            If IsEmpty(Target) Then _
                Target.Formula = salaries2`

Comment: That is probably in a worksheet_Change event and thus allows for the `ByVal Target As Range`  again just putting that in there does not make it work.  What I am saying is that your code has errors and that is why it is not doing anything.  if you remove the error handling the vbe will point them out to you.  You can put the error handling back in after you get it to work, but with it, you are not letting the VBE tell where the problem is.

Comment: You are correct. It was in a worksheet_change event. It is now giving me the object required error.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `ByVal Target As Range` and adding these two lines at the top. `Dim Target as Range` and `Set Target = ActiveCell`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Scott Craner's comment above: Note that the "If-Then" construct doesn't need any corresponding "End If" when you have only one statement on one line following "Then". But when the If construct contains more than one statement, as in your case, the code block must end with "End If". You have a line continuation symbol ( _) immediately after "Then". Try removing this and include an End If statement instead, like this:

```
Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)

Case Sheets("Wage Run").Range("B7")
    If Target.HasFormula = False Then
        Sheets("wage run").Range("B7").Copy
        Sheets("With Changes").Select
        Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("With Changes").Range("E2:AB138"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Wage Run").Range("D1"), Sheets("With Changes").Range("A2:A138"), 0), 1)).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
End Select
```

Comment: I think this helped, however the formula still didn't work.

Comment: The "Select" and "With" (after the edit) statements are not implemented correctly. (And since you mention that you want to connect the macro to a button, I suspect that what you need is technically a Sub procedure and not a function procedure). You maybe want to consider rephrasing the question in order to increase the chances of getting a good answer, see the MCVE guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments above, here is a very minimal example that seems to do what you are asking for, but without any other context. It works on a workbook with (at least) two sheets. Maybe useful as a starting point.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

' Paste a value into another sheet if the value is not a formula.

    Dim sourcecell As Range
    Dim targetcell As Range

    Set sourcecell = Sheets(1).Range("D8")
    Set targetcell = Sheets(2).Range("D8")

    If Not sourcecell.HasFormula Then targetcell = sourcecell

End Sub
```